# Can not compile mlpack C++ program on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, codeblocks, mlpack

i downloaded mlpack and its dependencies from ubuntu repos as described in the docs using :

`sudo apt-get install libmlpack-dev libmlpack-bin` and then i ran :

`pkg-config --cflags mlpack`

And `pkg-config --libs mlpack`

And `pkg-config --modversion mlpack`
to make sure everything works and i got the expected outputs. Now in codeblocks i put the mlpack library directory in the search directory and the pkg-config --cflags mlpack in the compiler options, and the pkg-config --libs mlpack in the linker options. But when i build it gives me ld errors: libraries were not found. What frustrates me is that i have done the exact same procedure with other C++ libraries like OpenCV and it worked. So any help ? Does anyone managed to get it work before on linux ?

------Update------

I managed to fix it by only adding -lmlpack and -larmadillo to the linker options and not adding all --libs.

Comment: Don't know how much help I can be, but ld is specifically the linker tool. If you remove the linker option you added, do you then get a compiler message? If not, seems like it's specifically an issue with your linker option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact error message and the executed command that produced the error message.